# How to programmatically record screen without root device in android?

Tags: android, video-capture

I have a drawing app. I want to record finger drawing and make .mp4 file. Display whole drawing steps for how to create drawing. I can't understand how to use record screen on my apps.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this, Jack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple solution, without using any 3rd party library using handler, generate screenshot and use frame animation for full screen mode. Thats its.

Answer (score 0):

You can not record screen video without rooting device.
But in your case if you want to play drawing then if you have state of your drawn items then you can redraw it in thread with proper delay, it will looks like video.

Comment: If i will use thread on my apps then whole finger drawing becomes slower.

Comment: In other words, record all the finger-movements together with a time-stamp of when they occur, then play them back at a later date according to the time-stamp.

Comment: but you will use thread while playing drawing again only not while drawing

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I want to add a precision: you can make a "screenshot" of what's on screen in your apps in any android version, by enabling the Drawing cache on a View. But this can not be used to record smooth videos.

Comment: after creating screenshots of apps then how to create video for it?